# How to preserve split view divider configuration in Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, mac-catalyst

Mac apps that have a sidebar (Mail, Finder, etc) allow you to resize its width, and that width is preserved across app launches. You enable this behavior in an AppKit app by assigning `autosaveName` on your `NSSplitView`. How do you do this in a Mac Catalyst app using `UISplitViewController`?

By default, my Catalyst app's sidebar is pretty wide, so every time the user opens it they have to resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to a friend who was able to achieve this in their app. They said you can manually save the current width to UserDefaults and upon creating the split view controller set its `preferredPrimaryColumnWidth` to the last saved width. Nice!

In my `UISplitViewController` subclass I added:

```
init() {
    let lastWidth = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "SidebarWidth")
    let initialWidth = lastWidth > 0 ? CGFloat(lastWidth) : 220
    preferredPrimaryColumnWidth = initialWidth
    
    //...
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Int(primaryColumnWidth), forKey: "SidebarWidth")
}
```